# What is the unit/army composition with the highest auto battle value?

Tags: warhammer-total-war

I am asking this question for each faction in the game, if that result in the answers being too long please do tell and I'll split this question for each faction.

I'll also accept answers that takes upkeep into consideration(most valuable for the upkeep paid) though primarily I am asking for the strongest unit/army.